# PlaceAutocompleteFragment can't resolved

Tags: android, google-places-api

In my app I have added Google Maps and they work fine. I want to add a PlaceAutocompleteFragment. I am using the key which I had already generate for maps and I have enable the option Places Api from google.console. I have added these to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

but when I try to use PlacesAutoCompleteFragment then Android Studio can't resolve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` didn't exist in version 8.3 of Google Play Services.

This isn't documented very well, but you can see on [this blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/12/autocomplete-widget-and-updated-place.html) that `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` was "announced" in December 2015.

You can also see [in the PlaceCompleteFragment Google code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteFragment/Application/build.gradle#l23) that they are using version 8.4 of GooglePlayServices.

I also had this problem, and updating Google Play Services is what made it work.

So, update Google Play Services in the SDK Manager, and then modify the build.gradle like so, and it should work:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

**Update**

In newer versions of Google Play Services, they have broken out the Google Places API, so you need to include it in addition to Maps and Location:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
```

Comment: ok! now I am updating the sdk manager. Can i remove the play-servises:8.0.4? If I keep only the play-services-maps and play-services-location will be ok?

Comment: @user4292106 Yes, it should be ok. The last line was including all of Google Play Services, which is not needed.

Comment: ok thanks! After a couple oh hours android studio finished with update!

Comment: i have one more question. I have implement the placeAutoCompleteFragment and it works fine. I am getting placeName and placeLatLng. When I get the placeLatLng I want to add a marker in map in same activity which implements the OnMapReadyCallback. I have try to add the listener for placeAutoCompleteFragment inside of onMapReady but it doesn't work. When I have the listener inside of the onCreate then the map isn't ready.

Comment: @user4292106  autocomplete in map get disappear all of the sudden