# GoogleApiClient gives "Wrong 1st argument type" when trying to use enableAutoManage() function

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-api-client, androidx, appcompatactivity

With the new migration to `androidx` instead of `android.v4` or other support libraries I'm having a tough time figuring out how to get the `GoogleApiClient.Builder()` to work. I currently have this setup:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(SomeActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
```

Where SomeActivity already extends `AppCompatActivity`. However, due to a recent migration to `androidx` libraries the `.enableAutoManage()` function states that I have the wrong argument type as I'm using the `androidx` version of `AppCompatActivity` `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: isn't there a AndroidX version of `GoogleApiClient`?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't found anything about that. Is there a different gradle implementation for that?

Comment: I'm not using AndroidX, but this is what I found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179459/supportmapfragment-does-not-support-androidx-fragment

Comment: I'll check on my gradle version and see some of the other things suggested here tomorrow since it's 4am here. I am already on version 16.0.0 so I don't  think it's that. Thank you so much for your help though. I'll see if any of these apply and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is also having this issue. What fixed it for me was updating my gradle version and android studio version to the latest which is referred in the link posted in the comments which has some other good suggestions. Also check whether some dependencies you have in your gradle/maven are updated as well since androidx is fairly new and some libraries have not migrated yet to it.