# androidX jetifier - Is there a way to ignore jetifying a .JAR?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

Trying to update my app to `androidX` dependencies. Followed instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), and compilation failed.
The error came from `JetifyTransform` task failing to process a certain .JAR dependency (FYI - [Samsungs Spass SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/release-note/view.do?v=R000000009)) :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsStandardNo_vendorDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:standardNo_vendorDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform file 'pass-v1.2.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
      > Failed to transform '/Users/hanandann/StudioProjects/ArnakPaymentsAndroid/Payments/app/libs/pass-v1.2.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform file 'pass-v1.2.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
      > Failed to transform '/Users/hanandann/StudioProjects/ArnakPaymentsAndroid/Payments/app/libs/pass-v1.2.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Trying to jetify with `jetifier-standalone` tool had similar results:

```
Hanans-MacBook-Pro:bin hanandann$ ./jetifier-standalone -i /Users/hanandann/StudioProjects/.../app/libs/pass-v1.2.2.jar -o /Users/hanandann/StudioProjects/.../app/libs/pass-v1.2.2jet.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readFrameType(ClassReader.java:2313)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readFrame(ClassReader.java:2269)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1448)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.ByteCodeTransformer.runTransform(ByteCodeTransformer.kt:39)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:443)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.ArchiveFile.accept(ArchiveFile.kt:49)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:425)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.Archive.accept(Archive.kt:76)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:421)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:247)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform$default(Processor.kt:234)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.standalone.Main.run(Main.kt:157)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.standalone.Main$Companion.main(Main.kt:109)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.standalone.Main.main(Main.kt)
```

Now, I don't really mind if SDK's don't get jetified, so I tried setting `android.enableJetifier=false` in my `gradle.properties` file, but compilation failed again for a different reason- `SupportMapFragment` isn't compatible with androidX yet as is reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51179606/4982218)

So I'm stuck. With jetify the .JAR won't transform. with it - SupportMapFarg is incompatible.

Any suggestions?

P.S. you know what would be nice? if there was an `ignore` option for the jetifying function

Comment: I got same error because some lib jar file was "malformed" or something, which was a deprecation warning in Gradle 4 and a fatal error in Gradle 5. Downgrading to Gradle 4 solved the issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

added this to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.jetifier.blacklist = pass
```

as suggested by folks at google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131207170#comment4).

Be warned - this feature is experimental and unsupported.

---

Update- current syntax is `android.jetifier.ignorelist={your.ignored.lib}` as Suggested by @YaMiN

Comment: This works for me and says "WARNING: The option setting 'android.jetifier.blacklist=pass' is experimental and unsupported.". Thanks.

Comment: This does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Any equivalent options for Xamarin android?

Answer (score 10):

Currently `android.jetifier.blacklist` is deprecated.

It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
This property has been replaced by `android.jetifier.ignorelist`

Answer (score 4):

Add this in project's gradle.properties:
`android.jetifier.blacklist =xx.aar,yy.jar`
split the black list with comma

update on 2022/06/07

If you use gradle 7, it change to `android.jetifier.ignorelist`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ignore just a specific .jar file from the jetifier. You can add the file name in the gradle.properties like on the last line from this example.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.jetifier.blacklist=liblinphone-4.0.1-debug-symbols.jar
```