# Failed to transform moshi-1.13.0.jar (failed for task biometric_storage:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, moshi, android-jetifier

I pulled a team's project that is made in Flutter from Git and for some reason when building the app (pressing the green arrow in Android Studio and running main.dart) I get the following message:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':biometric_storage:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':biometric_storage:kapt'.
   > Failed to transform moshi-1.13.0.jar (com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\UserName\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.moshi\moshi\1.13.0\da685586facab9eb5c4fb630ce248be14e7da21b\moshi-1.13.0.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\UserName\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.moshi\moshi\1.13.0\da685586facab9eb5c4fb630ce248be14e7da21b\moshi-1.13.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Unsupported class file major version 60. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Other maybe relevant info

```
Fluter Android Studio plugin 63.2.1
Dart Android Studio plugin 203.8452
Dart 2.15.1
Flutter 2.8.1
```

Nobody on my team gets this message so I suspect It has to do with some local configuration difference or maybe I have a different version of some program. Also, I can't update Gradle because that causes some other problems.
EDIT: After clearing the cache all of my teammates, got this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NOTE: I am the one who asked this question. The following solutions are independent and you can try just one of them or you can combine them. Choose the one that looks simpler and if that works then there is no need for the other ones.

**SOLUTION 1**

Try ignoring that one .jar that is causing the problem. You can do this by editing file **"gradle.properties"**.  Add `android.jetifier.blacklist`  or `android.jetifier.ignorelist`  ([LINK TO RELATED QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813882/androidx-jetifier-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-jetifying-a-jar)) depending on the version of Android Gradle plugin version that you are using (to check which version you use, go to your build.gradle and check `com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z` ). If you use anything before 7.0.0 use `android.jetifier.blacklist` and after use `android.jetifier.ignorelist`.

I use 3.6.0 so for me `android.jetifier.blacklist` works and `android.jetifier.ignorelist` does not.

**SOLUTION 2**

Try updating gradle and android gradle plugin to version 7. I did not try this and I can't because this isn't my personal project, but if you can go for it. Why I think upgrading will help? Well [this github issue](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1454#issuecomment-989981705) talks about that.

**SOLUTION 3**

The following solution doesn't make any sense (at least to me, if someone can explain why this fixes the problem please do), but for some strange reason it works.

I add a new library called [bye-bye-jetifier](https://github.com/dipien/bye-bye-jetifier) because my idea was that I should turn off jetifier. Prior to turning it off I have to check if I have any dependence that uses outdated code (the code that is not AndroidX) hence I decided to install bye-byte-jetifier. After installing my build.gradle looked like this. After running with the following config the problem was gone.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()   // <--------- I added this
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.dipien:bye-bye-jetifier:1.2.1' // <--------- I added this
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
```

Note that I didn't even apply the plugin (like the offical guide on  [bye-bye-jetifier](https://github.com/dipien/bye-bye-jetifier) says), that makes this solution even more confusing.

Comment: If I add to ignore list, I get 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
com.squareup.moshi.w.b.a

Comment: android.jetifier.blacklist = com.squareup.moshi - worked for me.

Comment: android.jetifier.ignorelist=android-base-common,common,moshi-1.13.0.jar.   worked for me, by doing this keyboard not open,

Answer (score 8):

file: "gradle.properties" (Project Properties)
adding line below

```
android.jetifier.blacklist = com.squareup.moshi
```

Comment: For Android Gradle plugin version BEFORE 7.0.0 use android.jetifier.blacklist.
For Android Gradle plugin version 7.0.0 and AFTER use android.jetifier.ignorelist

Answer (score 2):

2023 here,

Similar thing happened to me with my React Native app (v.0.64.2), when upgrading classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
to
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")

because of [stripe-terminal-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-react-native) among other requirements.
[SOLUTION 3 from Pero122's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878644/11890217) answer worked for me.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        // jcenter() // <-- jcenter() doesn't work anymore btw
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3") // <---- issue triggered when I updated to this
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.dipien:bye-bye-jetifier:1.2.1' // <--------- I added this
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude moshi library from all the project
Write this in build.gradle(app)

```
configurations.all { exclude group:"com.squareup.moshi" }
```

**Use carefully only when you know you don't use this library!**