# AutoComplete Search bar in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, searchbar

I'm creating an app based on places search. I would like to know how can I add a search bar into my Google Map, where the user can select a Place, and I can capture what the user chose.

I'm trying to include an autocomplete Search Box that is displayed above the Google Map in the UI.

Comment: PlacesAutoComplete Fragment is depreciated consider using PlacesAutoCompleteSupportFragment. see full answer and code at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356161/13339685

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use a [PlaceAutoCompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocompleteFragment).

First ensure that you're using the latest version of Google Play Services ([Version 8.4.0 and up includes the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801349/4409409)):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
```

Then include the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment in your xml layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Then set up a listener in your Activity:

```java
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
        placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

                Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

When you run this code, you'll see the AutoComplete bar above the Google Map:

[image]

When you click on the AutoComplete bar, it will look like this:

[image]

Then, start typing, and select a Place:

[image]

When you tap on a place to select it, you will see the log from the PlaceSelectionListener:

```
D/Maps: Place selected: San Francisco
```

Comment: That "placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener()" line giving NullPointerException! Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: @BigGuy Are you sure that you have set the ID correctly in the layout xml? In this example it's: `android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"`

Comment: @DanielNugent Fixed it. Actually there was an unknown problem with my activity. Created a new activity and it worked! Thank you !

Comment: The search bar loses focus soon after it is clicked. What is the issue?

Comment: @FahadSaleem Just enable the Places API from Google API console.

Comment: @Fahad Saleem Replace <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" /> from the manifest file with <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

Comment: The search bar loses focus soon after it is clicked. What is the issue? I tried the solutions given above!! @DanielNugent

Comment: @FahadSaleem hi did you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by make method for addMarker when you press on the place, You can use this code:

```
public class PlaceAutocompleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;

    LatLng myLat;
    Place placey;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_autocompleteplaces);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search about a Place");

        placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
        placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                addMarker(place);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapplaces);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    public void addMarker(Place p){

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        markerOptions.position(p.getLatLng());
        markerOptions.title(p.getName()+"");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(p.getLatLng()));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
    }
}
```

Comment: does it works? I have an issue on getting Autocomplete search view!